# How to delete a test project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, solution

Lately I had a problem (Could not load type '...' from assembly '...') with my test project (unit-test in Visual Studio 2010), so I tried (after looking for solutions here) deleting it and rewriting it. I deleted it by right-clicking on the project in Solution Explorer and choosing 'Remove'. Nevertheless, I can see that the project still exists, if I am looking in the folders (of the entire solution), through windows...

How can I correctly and completely delete the test project? (I have made a backup...)

Comment: Remove it from the solution, then drag the project folder to the Recycle Bin.

Comment: If you are using a source control then you have to make sure to check in your .sln file too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Removing* it from the project structure just modifies the solution file (.sln). After removing a project it's not anymore listed in there and the reference is gone.

So removing a project from the solution just removes the *reference* to the project. If you'd like to remove it entirely, delete it manually from its old location on the disk, as well.

Comment: I wonder why it's not possible to permanently delete (project) files inside VS. this way, especially if you work with source control, more and more zombie-files will pile up and this will lead to confusion... is there a workaround for dealing with this?

Comment: In my case the test case playlist was still there, so make sure to take a look to the solution for 'zombie' files as @beta said

Answer (score 9):

You almost do the right thing... You have to "Remove" from the Solution, by right clicking and "Remove" the project. This action will change the Solution (.sln) file, removing the reference to the project, but the folders will remain in the disk.
Then you have to delete it from the disk manually.

Comment: Oh, that simple? Thank you :)